# Create missing custom renderer for single platform

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I need to use [PdfViewer](https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/pdf-viewer/getting-started) from some library. This library provides control for Android, IOS, UWP platforms but not for WPF platform. How to create a renderer only for WPF platform?

WPF renderer:

```cs
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(PdfViewer), typeof(PdfViewerRenderer))]
public class PdfViewerRenderer : Xamarin.Forms.Platform.WPF.ViewRenderer<PdfViewer, WPF.PlatformImplementations.PdfViewer>
{

}
```

WPF control implementation:

```cs
namespace WPF.PlatformImplementations
{ 
    public class PdfViewer 
    { 
     //custom implementation of pdf viewer for wpf
    } 
}
```

Net standard library contains PdfViewer which derives from SfPdfViewer from a library:

```cs
namespace Views
{ 
    public class PdfViewer : SfPdfViewer 
    { 
     //implementation of pdf viewer using base class from multiplatform library
    } 
}
```

The above approach does not work for WPF and works for other platforms. When I change inheritance from SfPdfViewer to Xamarin.Forms.View then it works for WPF but obviously does not work for other platforms. So the problem is to make renderer mechanizm to recognize Views.PdfViewer as control based on Xamarin.Forms.View.

Comment: One way to do this is to create a `CustomPdfViewer` interface in the Core project, and have individual implementations in each native project using Dependency injection. In the native implementations for each of the iOS, Android, & UWP projects, just make it use the PdfViewer library that works for you. And then for WPF, just use the SfPdfViewer instead.

Comment: @Saamer approach seems correct

Comment: If you have purchased their subscription they will probably add support for WPF if you request

Comment: @Prateek it already has been reported: https://www.syncfusion.com/feedback/8105/support-for-pdf-viewer-in-xamarin-forms-wpf

Answer (score 3):

Every `Xamarin.Forms` control has a accompanying renderer for each platform that needs to **create an instance of a native control**.

`SfPdfViewer` is a xamarin-forms control that only represents the shared UI state, and interaction logic. It needs a corresponding native control to actually render the view and interact with `WPF` platform.

In order to do that, first step would be to choose a `WPF` based control for viewing PDF files. For this example I have used [WPF Pdf Viewer by SyncFusion](https://help.syncfusion.com/wpf/pdf-viewer/overview); but any other option - probably like an embedded [WebView](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Toolkit.Wpf.UI.Controls.WebView) or an open-source option like [PdfiumViewer](https://github.com/pvginkel/PdfiumViewer) should also work.

## Step 1:

Install nuget package for [Syncfusion.PdfViewer.WPF](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Syncfusion.PdfViewer.WPF/) in WPF project

## Step 2:

Wire up the with forms-element (`SfPdfViewer`) with native-control (`PdfViewerControl`) using platform renderer.

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(SfPdfViewer), typeof(SfPdfViewerRenderer))]
namespace PdfViewer.Demo.WPF
{
    public class SfPdfViewerRenderer
        : ViewRenderer<SfPdfViewer, Syncfusion.Windows.PdfViewer.PdfViewerControl>
    {
        Syncfusion.Windows.PdfViewer.PdfViewerControl _nativeControl;

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<SfPdfViewer> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            // If new forms element attached, wire up the native control
            if (e.NewElement != null)
            {
                _nativeControl = new Syncfusion.Windows.PdfViewer.PdfViewerControl();
                SetNativeControl(_nativeControl);
            }
            // Otherwise perform some cleanup
            else
            {
                if(_nativeControl != null)
                {
                    _nativeControl.Unload();
                    _nativeControl = null;
                }
            }

            UpdateNativeControlProperties();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Basically sync property values from forms-element (SfPdfViewer) 
        /// to native-control (PdfViewerControl)
        /// In this example - we only sync with 'input file stream'
        /// </summary>
        private void UpdateNativeControlProperties()
        {
            if (Element != null && Element.InputFileStream != null)
            {
                Control.Load(Element.InputFileStream);
            }
            else
            {
                Control.Unload();
            }
        }

        protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);

            if (e.PropertyName == nameof(SfPdfViewer.InputFileStream))
            {
                UpdateNativeControlProperties();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### Reference sample project uploaded on [Github](https://github.com/dotnext-dev/DemoSfPdfViewerOnWPF).

[image: Demo]

Comment: @FreakyAli : As I mentioned in the answer - we should be able to use any WPF PDF viewer. As the question is about a SyncFusion library - I used that in the sample.

Comment: Yeah I am aware I was just confirming whether or not it's paid!

Comment: @FreakyAli : They do seem to have a [Community License](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense)

Comment: Thank you for help. This answer helped me the most so the bounty goes here.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to create a `CustomPdfViewer` interface in the Core project, and have individual implementations in each native project using Dependency injection.

In the native implementations for each of the iOS, Android, & UWP projects, just make it use the `PdfViewer` library that works for you.

And then for WPF, just use the `SfPdfViewer` instead.

Eg: You can take a look at the [official documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/photo-picker) on DependencyService with examples

Once you do this, you will have your solution. But if you want to go one step further and access the `CustomPdfViewer` you created inside your XAML, you can use "[XAML Markup Extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/markup-extensions/creating)" represented by the term `local` as you can also see in the example [here](https://www.dylanberry.com/2019/12/05/opening-urls-from-xaml/).

Comment: I am not sure how to use it in XAML and with custom renderer?

Comment: I know how DI works. It does not solve the problem. My question is about creating control in native platform and use it via custom renderer in xaml.

Comment: @raV720, As it is mentioned here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/renderers "Every Xamarin.Forms control has an accompanying renderer for each platform that creates an instance of a native control". Are you using Xamarin.Forms controls or libraries, because only XF controls allow you to use Custom Renderers?

Comment: Please read the question carefully, especially last paragraph. The problem is not so obvious. Of course I use XF controls and native controls as it should be used - as I have mentioned in question it works under some circumstances.